# How can I use nessrest api (python) to export nessus scan reports in xml?

Tags: python-2.7, nessus

I am trying to automate the running of and downloading nessus scans using python. I have been using the nessrest api for python, and am able to successfully run a scan, but am not being successfully download the report in nessus format.

Any ideas how I can do this? I have been using the module scan_download, but that actually executes before my scan even finishes.

Thanks for the help in advance!

Comment: you have to "export" the report prior to downloading. 

you can check the state of a ongoing scan using the /status API-methode.

the workflow should look like this: getToken(), startScan(), checkIfFinished(), export(), download()

Answer (score 0):

Just looking back at this question, heres an example of using Nessrest API to pull down CSV report exports from you nessus host,

```
#!/usr/bin/python2.7
import sys
import os
import io
from nessrest import ness6rest 

file_format = 'csv'  # options: nessus, csv, db, html
dbpasswd = ''

scan = ness6rest.Scanner(url="https://nessus:8834", login="admin", password="P@ssword123", insecure=True)

scan.action(action='scans', method='get')
folders = scan.res['folders']
scans = scan.res['scans']

if scan:
    scan.action(action='scans', method='get')
    folders = scan.res['folders']
    scans = scan.res['scans']

    for f in folders:
        if not os.path.exists(f['name']):
            if not f['type'] == 'trash':
                os.mkdir(f['name'])

    for s in scans:
        scan.scan_name = s['name']
        scan.scan_id = s['id']
        folder_name = next(f['name'] for f in folders if f['id'] == s['folder_id'])
        folder_type = next(f['type'] for f in folders if f['id'] == s['folder_id'])

        # skip trash items
        if folder_type == 'trash':
            continue

        if s['status'] == 'completed':
            file_name = '%s_%s.%s' % (scan.scan_name, scan.scan_id, file_format)
            file_name = file_name.replace('\\','_')
            file_name = file_name.replace('/','_')
            file_name = file_name.strip()
            relative_path_name = folder_name + '/' + file_name
            # PDF not yet supported
            # python API wrapper nessrest returns the PDF as a string object instead of a byte object, making writing and correctly encoding the file a chore...
            # other formats can be written out in text mode
            file_modes = 'wb'
            # DB is binary mode
            #if args.format == "db":
            #  file_modes = 'wb'
            with io.open(relative_path_name, file_modes) as fp:
                if file_format != "db":
                    fp.write(scan.download_scan(export_format=file_format))
                else:
                    fp.write(scan.download_scan(export_format=file_format, dbpasswd=dbpasswd))
```

can see more examples here,

https://github.com/tenable/nessrest/tree/master/scripts